# Email Validity Check

Tags: android

I used this code to check validity of my Email. However this's working. It always show Invalid Email over and over again.

```
private boolean isValidEmail(String email){
    boolean isValidEmail = false;

    String regExpn = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+";

    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExpn, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (email.matches(regExpn))
    {
        isValidEmail = true;
    }
    return isValidEmail;
}
```

Here is the method call

```
else if(!isValidEmail(edit_txt_EmailAddress.toString().trim()))
{
 showAlertDialog(Login.this, "Email", "Enter Valid Email", false);
 edit_txt_EmailAddress.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: http://rajareddypolam.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/how-to-validate-username-with-regular-expression/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the method call:

> isValidEmail(edit_txt_EmailAddress.getText().toString().trim())

Answer (score 4):

Android has built-in pattern matcher. You can try this by following code.

```
public final static boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use the following methods:

```
private boolean validEmail(String email) {
        Pattern pattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        return pattern.matcher(email).matches();
    }
```

inside the code write the following Code:

```
if (!validEmail(registerEmailET.getText().toString())) {
                    //show error
Toast.makeText(this,"Invalid Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show;
                    return;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
public static boolean isEmailValiddate(String email) {
Pattern pattern = Pattern
 .compile("\\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
if (!matcher.find()) {
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
    boolean isValid = false;

    String expression = "^[\\w\\.-]+@([\\w\\-]+\\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$";
    CharSequence inputStr = email;

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        isValid = true;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: It's parsing valid mail addresses as invalid: E.g. `foo+bar@gmail.com` is valid. `foo@mail.imabillionaireandcaneffortrunningafancynewtld` is soon to be valid. Even `foo_bar@yahoo.com` is valid.

Comment: don't panic  all this from my side with my code is run very smooth dear

Comment: i check all your pattern with my this method first u check yourself

Answer (score 0):

Used  in-build matcher for validation.

```
if(android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher("xyz@gmail.com").matches()){

}
else{
        //invalid
    }
```

Note: Its work with Api level 8 and above.

Alterante# Using regex, try out below code:

```
// BOOLEAN METHOD TO CHECK THE PATTERN OF THE EMIL-ID INPUT BY THE USER
    public static boolean isEmail(String email) {
        boolean matchFound1;
        boolean returnResult = true;
        email = email.trim();
        if (email.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            returnResult = false;
        else if (!Character.isLetter(email.charAt(0)))
            returnResult = false;
        else {
            Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile("^\\.|^\\@ |^_");
            Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(email.toString());
            matchFound1 = m1.matches();


            Pattern p = Pattern
                    .compile("^[a-zA-z0-9._-]+[@]{1}+[a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1}+[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$");
            // Match the given string with the pattern
            Matcher m = p.matcher(email.toString());

            // check whether match is found
            boolean matchFound = m.matches();

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(email, ".");
            String lastToken = null;
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                lastToken = st.nextToken();
            }
            if (matchFound && lastToken.length() >= 2
                    && email.length() - 1 != lastToken.length()
                    && matchFound1 == false) {

                returnResult = true;
            } else
                returnResult = false;
        }
        return returnResult;
    }
```